# Can we say that go-getter is associated with risk taking!

Tags: meaning, word-usage

If a person is someone who is taking risks in his life can we say he is go-getter one. What I mean - if you change jobs, and invest in different stocks, companies etc. can we say that person is go-getter?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is overlap but it's not a perfect fit.

"go getter" implies a person who works aggressively and outshines their peers. They put more energy into pursuing things that others don't. It's as likely that they pursue traditional directions (not taking actual risks at all) and just put more work into it.

It wouldn't be incorrect to describe the person that way but it would not imply risk taking or originality by that person.

Also, "go getter" is a slightly dated term. For that reason it can be used to imply that the person has an outdated "aggressive business person" perspective.

Answer (score 1):

I would say not

- A "go-getter" is a person who is active, "pro-active" in current vocabulary, a "self-starter" in slightly older business vocabulary (All quite US sounding to my UK ears.)
- A "risk-taker" might be the word you're after